# Are flash-forwards ever used as literary devices?

Tags: character-development, science-fiction, time-depiction, plot-structure

Flashbacks are common in books and movies. People only perceive linear time in that they only have knowledge of the past, even when those memories might seem to be artificially planted.

What are the most popular usages of flash-forwards in classic literature and modern cinema, where a character seems to have 'memory' of the future? If it's not called memory, what is it.

Comment: The technical term is a premonition or a precognition. It won't appear outside of prophetic religious literature or science fiction, I believe.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashforward) has examples, and [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlashForward) has more. Questions just asking for examples aren't really in the spirit of Stack Exchange, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Premonitions and precognition

These are the terms used to describe your literary device in science fiction. Many examples exist throughout science fiction literature. One of the most well known is the 1956 short story *Minority Report* by Phillip K. Dick, which features "precogs" who can see the future and predict crime. The protagonist is a police officer who pursues future-crime arresting people before the crime occurs.

### Prophecy

This is the word used for your phenomenon both in and outside of science fiction. Religious literature may use prophecy or "divine visions" to determine actions, and adjust the story plot in literature. The general line which makes the literary device a vision or prophecy is that the source has some *agency* within your narrative. The vision comes by way of a divine or otherwise supernatural character in the story. Prophecy is generally “given” to your character vice something they personally experienced or obtained by their own volition.

This device won't happen in a non-fiction setting except as an illustration of some false narrative.

Answer (score -2):

Stories are written using points of view and verb-tense e.g 1st Person POV  past tense or 3rd Person POV past tense.  It can just as well be present tense, it is a choice by the author.

When a story was told in the past-tense verb tense, then time is fluid.  The narrator can move the moment in the story back in time or forward in time, since everything is past tense.

Given that, as an author of a story, if you chose present tense for the narrative, you could still move the story into the future if you felt your story needed that.

The only concerns are making it clear when your story is jumping ahead of itself, but that is the same problem as time-shifts to the past -- flash backs